# Erdos Number Technicalities

Tags: path-connected

Imagine this:
I publish a paper with my friend who doesn't yet have and Erdos number.
He later gets an Erdos number of 4, or any number for that matter.
Is my Erdos number automatically 5 (one greater than my friends), or do I need to publish another paper with him?

Comment: While I doubt this question is on topic, an Erdos number is graph theoretic in that either you have one because you are path connected to Erdos through publishing papers, or you are not. So after your friend publishes a paper with Erdos (which would be quite a feat today) you'd have an Erdos number one greater than him.

Comment: Yeah, I know its not really on topic but OK, thanks.

Comment: I can accept the answer if you post that comment as an answer.